# SwiftUI DatePicker returns wrong time when selecting default value with closed data range

Tags: swift, swiftui

Setup a `DatePicker` in SwiftUI running on iOS 13.5; limit the date range for an hour from now to seven days from now. Open the view, select the default value and observe that the time is off by exactly an hour! If you change the default value, the date will be correct! The offset is however much start date is different from current date.

```
import SwiftUI

private func eligibleDateRange() -> ClosedRange<Date> {
    let now = Date()
    let start = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 60, to: now)!
    let end = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: +7, to: now)!
    return start...end
}

struct PickDateView: View {
    @State private var selectedDate = Date()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker(selection: $selectedDate, in: eligibleDateRange()) {
                Text("")
            }
            Button(action: {
                // Prints out 7:38, when I selected 8:38!!
                // Note that I am using .current to print in current timezone. 
                print(self.selectedDate.description(with: .current))
            }) {
                Text("Continue")
            }
        }
     }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Works as expected (with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4). Your initial date is out-of-range. It is your responsibility to set up initial values for control work, it modifies selection only on change.

Comment: I am on iOS 13.5, xCode 11.5; how is the initial date out of range? I am just tapping on the default value, without changing the scroll wheel, and the output date is off by however much start time is different now. It reproduces every time on my end.

Comment: So let's say right now is 8pm, I allow the customer to pick times between 9pm to 10pm. The default value of DatePicker is 9, I tap continue, it prints 8pm.

Comment: Consider that `print` displays dates in UTC. It's certainly not a SwiftUI bug. If your time zone is UTC+1 the date is correct.

Comment: @vadian (1) I am using .current timezone for printing the date, even then, just extract the timestamp and convert yourself, the time is off! (2) the issue happens only when you select default value, every other time it works, so this is not a timezone issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Asperi indicated `selectedDate` is outside of the `eligibleDateRange` upon initialisation (approx an hour early). Without **picking a new time**, `selectedDate` will not change, hence `selectedDate` will still be approx. an hour before the `eligableDataRange`.

The `selection` parameter of `DatePicker` is a `Binding<Date>`. I do not think it is very surprising the setter of that binding is not called upon initialisation of the DatePicker or without manually selecting a new date.

Of course the desired behaviour can be easily created by initialising selected date to `eligibleDateRange().lowerBound`. Or clamping the date to the `eligableDateRange`.

```
import SwiftUI

private func clamp<T: Comparable>(_ value: T, range: ClosedRange<T>) -> T {
    max(min(value, range.upperBound), range.lowerBound)
}

private func eligibleDateRange() -> ClosedRange<Date> {
    let now = Date()
    let start = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 60, to: now)!
    let end = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: +7, to: now)!
    return start...end
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedDate = clamp(Date(), range: eligibleDateRange())
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker(selection: $selectedDate, in: eligibleDateRange()) {
                Text("")
            }
            Button(action: {
                print(self.selectedDate.description(with: .current))
            }) {
                Text("Continue")
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: >  I do not think it is very surprising the setter of that binding is not called upon initialization of the DatePicker or without manually selecting a new date.

Would you consider this a bug? `DatePicker` should init binding with its default value.

Comment: I do not think this a bug (strictly speaking it is if the behavior isn’t documented, but Apple isn’t very strict with documentation). There is no ‘default’ value. The closest thing to the default value is the value upon initialisation. To me it is a sane implementation decision not to change that value automatically, but it still is an implementation decision. I just checked the documentation and the behavior isn’t specified. At best/worst you can conclude the documentation is incomplete (but this case is really nitpicking considering the state of the documentation)